# Page x of y footer with multiple user-specified display enhancements

Tags: fonts, header-footer, page-numbering, italic

**Using the following packages and code I am able to produce a footer with the text "Page x of y" in the font size that I want.**

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\cfoot{\smaller[2]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

**My question is, how do I also add italics and change the font face of this footer?** Here are all of the specifications I would like to make for the footer. The first three are taken care of. I have chosen a font available in Overleaf. I tried adding `\textin`, `\emph`, and `\em` at random places in the `\cfoot` command without any visible change to the display. I did not even know how to attempt changing the font face within the `\cfoot` command.

- <s>Center footer</s>
- <s>Footer content Page x of y</s>
- <s>Make footer size smaller either as a relative size or as a specified point
  size.</s>
- **Specify footer font as Noto Serif**
- **Italicize footer**

**My entire document with Thai lorem ipsum in case there is a conflict between packages.**

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=17pt,
  openany,
%  BCOR=5mm,
  paper=a4paper,
  DIV=15,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  margin=1in,
  footskip=.5in,
%  paper=a4paper
]{geometry}

% paragraph first line indentation
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\parindent=.5in

% discourage widows. Set to 10000 to forbid
\widowpenalty=500

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{thai}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily\thaifont[Script=Thai]{Noto Serif Thai}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Garuda:script=thai}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
%\PolyglossiaSetup{thai}{indentfirst=true}

%\raggedright
\usepackage{relsize}

% Packages needed for header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%%%%% 
% Footer content Page x of y
% Specify footer font as Noto Serif
% Italicize footer
% Center footer
% Make footer size smaller either as a relative size or as a specified point size.

\cfoot{\smaller[2]{\emph Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%\setlength{\baselineskip}{38.5pt}
คิดเดินทางอินเทอร์เน็ตสนับสนุนทั่วไปอินเทอร์เน็ตความหมายหญิง สวนคิดท่องเที่ยวใจถึงอาชีพ หนังสืออาชีพอาศัย ทำงาน ข่าวเด็กอาศัยชายหญิงธรรมชาติพักผ่อนหญิงถ่ายรูป เด็กแยกแยะ อาศัยคนแก่เดินทาง พักผ่อนสื่อเดินทางแยกแยะข่าวเดินทางเศรษฐกิจทำงานอ่านคำนึงแยกแยะความหมายหนังสือ อินเทอร์เน็ตอาศัยทั่วไป หญิงวิเคราะห์เดินทางเด็กถึงคิดเด็กอาชีพคนแก่ท่องเที่ยว คำนึงชายคิดทั่วไปสวนทำงานคำนึงอาศัยคำนึงทั่วไปสนับสนุนวิเคราะห์สนับสนุนเด็กทำงานถึง คิดใจพักผ่อนคำนึงคิดมาก
ยะหนั
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=17pt,
  openany,
%  BCOR=5mm,
  paper=a4paper,
  DIV=15,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  margin=1in,
  footskip=.5in,
%  paper=a4paper
]{geometry}

% paragraph first line indentation
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\parindent=.5in

% discourage widows. Set to 10000 to forbid
\widowpenalty=500

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{thai}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\newfontfamily\thaifont[Script=Thai]{Noto Serif Thai}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Garuda:script=thai}
\newfontfamily{\noto}{Noto Sans}
\setotherlanguage{english}

%\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
%\PolyglossiaSetup{thai}{indentfirst=true}

%\raggedright
\usepackage{relsize}

% Packages needed for header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%%%%% 
% Footer content Page x of y
% Specify footer font as Noto Serif
% Italicize footer
% Center footer
% Make footer size smaller either as a relative size or as a specified point size.

\cfoot{%
    \noto\smaller[4]{%
        \emph{%
            Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
        }
    }
}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%\setlength{\baselineskip}{38.5pt}
คิดเดินทางอินเทอร์เน็ตสนับสนุนทั่วไปอินเทอร์เน็ตความหมายหญิง สวนคิดท่องเที่ยวใจถึงอาชีพ หนังสืออาชีพอาศัย ทำงาน ข่าวเด็กอาศัยชายหญิงธรรมชาติพักผ่อนหญิงถ่ายรูป เด็กแยกแยะ อาศัยคนแก่เดินทาง พักผ่อนสื่อเดินทางแยกแยะข่าวเดินทางเศรษฐกิจทำงานอ่านคำนึงแยกแยะความหมายหนังสือ อินเทอร์เน็ตอาศัยทั่วไป หญิงวิเคราะห์เดินทางเด็กถึงคิดเด็กอาชีพคนแก่ท่องเที่ยว คำนึงชายคิดทั่วไปสวนทำงานคำนึงอาศัยคำนึงทั่วไปสนับสนุนวิเคราะห์สนับสนุนเด็กทำงานถึง คิดใจพักผ่อนคำนึงคิดมาก
ยะหนั
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this snipit both as presented here and  by copying the \cfoot command into my original document. Neither shows the font change. The first option doesn't recognize smaller or \emph and the second doesn't recognize \emph.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing … I have changed my answer to a full MWE. This compiles fine for me using `XeLaTeX.` Note that I used `\smaller[4]` to better be able to observe the effects.